# React - setTimeout triggers style change for wrong components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/204131/

A parent component has two 'notifications' that it renders with different 'decay' rates.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notifications: [
        { message: "I am the first component", code: 1, decay: 2000 },
        { message: "I am the second component", code: 2, decay: 5000 }
      ]
    }

    this.dismissNotification = this.dismissNotification.bind(this)
  }

  dismissNotification(code) {
    this.setState({ notifications: this.state.notifications.filter(
      n => n.code != code
    )})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
        this.state.notifications.map( (n, idx) => {
          return (
            <Notification 
              key={idx}
              code={n.code} 
              decay={n.decay} 
              dismiss={this.dismissNotification}
            > 
                {n.message} 
            </Notification>
          )
        })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The components set their own timeOut which will cause an animation and then send a message for them to be dismissed.

```
class Notification extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      style: { opacity: 1 }
    }
    this.makeRedFunction = this.makeRedFunction.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let timeout = parseInt(this.props.decay) || 2000

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.makeRedFunction();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dismiss();
      }, 125)
    }, timeout)     
  }

  fadeOutFunction = () => {
    let opacity = Math.floor(this.state.style.opacity * 10)
    if (opacity > 0) {
      opacity -= 1
      setTimeout( () => { this.fadeOutFunction() }, 10)
    }
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state.style)
    newState.opacity = opacity / 10
    this.setState({ style: newState })
  }

  makeRedFunction = () => {
    this.setState({ style: {color: 'red'} })
  }

  dismiss = () => {
    this.props.dismiss(this.props.code)
  }

  render () {
    return(
       <div style={this.state.style}>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Unforunately, the style seems to change for *both* notifications when the dismiss function has been called for only *one* of them.

In general there is strange behavior with the mounting lifecycle of the components with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Don't use array indexes as keys if elements in the list have state. Use something that is unique for each data point and does not depend on its position in the array. In your case that would be `key={n.code}`.

---

This is related to how React reconciles the component tree and is a good example for why using array index as `key`s doesn't always produce the expected outcome.

When you are mutating a list of elements, the `key` helps React to figure out which nodes it should reuse. In your case are going from

```
<Notification />
<Notification />
```

to

```
<Notification />
```

But how should React know whether to delete the first or second `<Notification />` node? It does that by using `key`s. Assume we have

```
<Notification key="a">Foo</Notification>
<Notification key="b">Bar</Notification>
```

Now if it gets either

```
<Notification key="a">...</Notification>
```

or

```
<Notification key="b">...</Notification>
```

in the next render cycle it knows to remove the `<Notification />` with `key` `"b"` (or `"a"`).

However, your problem is that you base the `key` on the position of the data in the array. So on the first render you pass

```
<Notification key="0">First</Notification>
<Notification key="1">Second</Notification>
```

Then you are removing the first notification from the list, which changes the position of the second notification in the array, so React gets

```
<Notification key="0">Second</Notification>
```

which means

> remove the element with key `1` and update the element with key `0` to show "Second"

But the element with `key="0"` already had its style changed to red text, so you see the text from the second notification in red.

---

Have a look [at the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) for more information.

Comment: Wow beautiful, makes perfect sense!